# Find vector $y$ that is orthogonal to $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is

> A vector $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is given by$$\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-1\\3\end{bmatrix}$$
>   1. Find a vector $\mathbf{y}$ that is orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}$.

I'm confused how to find $y$, when vi just have one vector $x$?

Comment: You need $x \cdot y = 0$ for $x$ and $y$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: There are many vectors $y$ which are orthogonal to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an infinite number of answers. The simplest way is probably just to construct a vector that has a dot product of zero with this vector. For example:
$$v=\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right]$$

Note that:
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\-1\\3\end{array}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\1\\0\end{array}\right]=1+0-1+0=0$$

Comment: Okay, so the point is to construct a vector by my self.

Answer (score 2):

It has to satisfy the relation
$$x+2y-z+3t=0$$
which is the equation of the hyperplane orthogonal to $\mathbf x$. For instance $(1,0,1,0)$. But there are many others, since this hyperplane has dimension $3$.